# Autotools configure script command line installation bypass pressing Return key

Tags: ubuntu, configure, autotools

While installing netsnmp when i issue ./configure the command line window asks for "Press return to continue". How can i bypass this? I tried adding defaults=yes but didnt workout.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out the read input from configure script